# How to use a single jquery mobile page event for multiple php profile pages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

pls i'm trying to use jquery mobile page event to trigger ajax each time a profile page is loaded, the profile.php  is a single file accepting `GET variable which is the username`, my problem is that the code execute once.

```
var page = $('.profile').attr('data-username');
$(document).on("pageshow",' .profile_'+page+'', function(){ 
var id = $('.profile_'+page+'').attr('data-id');
function pin (){
$.ajax({
method : 'POST',
url: 'pin.php',
data: {user_id: id},
success: function(data){
$('#pinned_m_box_'+id+'').html(data); 
}
}) 

}
pin()
})
```

Comment: Please provide full js code, and also  provide file name. Are you trying to call pageshow event for multiple pages(as per your question) or same page multiple times.

Comment: @amitwadhwani same page multiple times, that is my full js code for now, am i lacking something? Thanks

Comment: hard code parameter "page" and let me know if you still face same problem, also copy full html here pls.

Comment: Use `pagecontainershow` event. Remove second argument, you can't delegate pagecontainer events.